# C++ SFML member initializer

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm really confused at the moment.  It's been a while since I touched C++ and I want to get back into it again, so I'm trying to use SFML, and I'm using a guide along side it.  The thing that gets me is this code.

```
Game::Game():mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application") {
}
```

It works perfectly, and I think I understand.  It's initializing mWindow, and when mWindow is constructed, it creates the window.  No problem.  But when I put this code down.

```
Game::Game() {
    mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
}
```

It gives me the error `Type 'sf::RenderWindow' does not provide a call operator`which I have no idea what that means, nor do I understand how those two blocks of code differ.

Comment: FYI: if for one reason or another you cannot use the initializer list, you can use `mWindow.create(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mWindow` should be a class data member, not a function.

[First block of code simply initializes it.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)

Comment: I don't think that it is a function, it just simply a constructor for sf::RenderWindow.  My main question is why does initializing it outside of body of the constructor work, but it won't work inside?  I couldn't find anything in that web page to suggest why, or maybe I'm dense

Comment: All of the answers here are somewhat correct. mWindow is not a function, YOU'RE RIGHT, but you're using it like it is a function. @Petr showed how you should use it when it's not in init-list.

Comment: Ok, so if that's a function, then what is     sf::RenderWindow mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
 Because that works apparently, though the window won't show.

Comment: Because if you do that in your constructor you're just creating a temporary object that will not only _shadow_ your member variable named `mWindow`, but go out of scope and destroy at the end of the constructor. You need to have another read up on how constructors work.

Comment: Alright that does make more sense, thank you all, I appreciate everyone's responses.  I definitely understand this a lot better.

Answer (score 1):

The error it's giving you is because in your second example, this:

```
mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
```

Should be this:

```
mWindow = sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application";
```

It's not going to work anyway, as `sf:RenderWindow` inherits from `sf::NonCopyable`.

The error is actually quite descriptive, **'sf::RenderWindow' does not provide a call operator**. `mWindow` is of type `sf::RenderWindow`. You're trying to *call* it like a function, `mWindow()`, which it is not.

You should use the *initializer list* in your first example. This will ensure the the `mWindow` member is constructed *once*.

Answer (score 0):

This is called [Constructor Initialization Lists](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/) and it actually should be something like this in your second example:

```
Game::Game() {
    this.mWindow = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application");
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't work, just says that there is not viable overload for the = operator.  Also, if I put this in main,     sf::RenderWindow mWindow(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "SFML Application"); , it works perfectly fine.

Comment: And what's the type of `mWindow` in your `Game` class?

Comment: That's because `sf::RenderWindow` inherits from `sf:NonCopyable`.